# How to addClass to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this bit of javascript to add a class to multiple elements. I trying to reference multiple divs and addClass to them. it Only works on the first one.

**Javascript**

```
<script>            
            $(function(){           
            if ( $(window).width() < 230 ) {
              $('#item1').addClass('col1'); //max-width 80px

            }
            else 
                if ( $(window).width() >= 230 && $(window).width() < 330 ) {
              $('#item1').addClass('col2'); //max-width 180px

            }
            else 
           {
              $('#item1').addClass('col3'); //max-width 280px

            }

          });
        </script>
```

it's working if I only have one #item1 on the page but it doesn't seem to want to add the class to multiple items that exist in the same div id. I even tried adding the class to multiple items that exist in the same div class rather than id. Either one would be a good solution for mw if you can figure it out.

**My HTML code is**

```
    <div id="item1" class="blue">
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
<div class="slider-range"></div>
</div>

<div id="item1" class="blue">
<label for="amount2">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount2" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"/>
<div class="slider-range2"></div>
</div>
```

Been trying to figure this out for a few hours now so I thought I'd ask to see if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using jQuery, so I added that tag for you.

Comment: Have you considered media queries?

Comment: The id of an element should be unique on the page. What you are trying to do shouldn't work. Use a class instead.

Comment: @One Trick Pony how to put it into a window re-size event as u recommended?

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function(...` should work. But Šime's advice with media queries is a better choice. That way you don't need JS and extra classes at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs should be unique.  Try adding a class instead, like "item":

```
<div class="blue item">
    ...etc...
</div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$('.item').addClass('col1');
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the class is getting added to only one div is because id's are supposed to be unique in the HTML. jQuery will only return the first matched item when using an id selector. You have three options

Option one: Instead of the id `item1` use a class `item` and use the following selector

```
$('.item').addClass('col1');
```

Option two: Change the id on the second div to `item2` and use the following selector

```
$('#item1, #item2').addClass('col1');
```

Option three: Use the attribute selector (this is more of a hack)

```
$('div[id="item1"]').addClass('col1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of `id` for the manipulation:

i.e.

```
var newClass = '';
if ( $(window).width() < 230 ) {
    newClass = 'col1';
}
else if ( $(window).width() >= 230 && $(window).width() < 330 ) {
    newClass = 'col2';
}
else {
    newClass = 'col3';
}

$('.blue').addClass(newClass); // will apply to all elements with class blue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one element with the same `id` per page. `ID` must be unique.

Change all of the `<div id="item1">` tags to `<div class="item1">`, and then your jQuery would look like this:

```
        <script>            
            $(function(){           
            if ( $(window).width() < 230 ) {
              $('.item1').addClass('col1'); //max-width 80px

            }
            elseif ( $(window).width() >= 230 && $(window).width() < 330 ) {
              $('.item1').addClass('col2'); //max-width 180px

            }
            else 
           {
              $('.item1').addClass('col3'); //max-width 280px

            }

          });
        </script>
```

Comment: $('.item1') will always return all the elements with that class.

Comment: That's what the user is trying to accomplish. Read the question before you downvote.

Comment: I understood the question, just didn't thoroughly read your answer.  Edit the answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use class selectors instead of id:

```
$('.toAdd').addClass('col3');
```

This will add class 'col3' to all elements wich have the class 'toAdd'.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple elements with the same id is not a valid syntax, and the id selector in jQuery `$('#anyId')` always return first item with that id, never multiple items.

use `<div class="blue item">` in your html and jQuery class selector `$('.item')` instead.